# COLLATION UNICODE_CI_AI for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed

Tags: firebird

I'm trying to set up a Docker container just to read a Firebase 3.0 database file.

Starting with a `ubuntu:20.04` base image and basically just installing `firebird3.0-server` I get a running container.

When openin a specific .fdb Database from *within* the container itself (`isql-fb` via `docker exec`), I can read the database fine.

However, when opening the same file via a remote connection (another Ubuntu 20.04 container), I get the error `COLLATION UNICODE_CI_AI for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed`.

The same setup using Firebird 2.5 (and a 2.5 FDB file) works fine.

I'm not sure what exactly that error means and if I need to fix it in the client or server container.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With some hints found [on this page](http://www.tpersistent.com/?cat=3&paged=2) I managed to resolve the problem by manually installing `libicu52` from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libicu52/52.1-3).

Quote from that page:

> Reading the “Release notes for Firebird 3.06″ I saw they had upgraded
> the ICU libraries to v52.1 so I downloaded the [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libicu52/52.1-3) and installed
> it.

I used base image `ubuntu:18.04` but I guess it would work on Ubuntu 20 as well.